# Check and Swap Button? GUI [is there a action command for that?]

Tags: java, user-interface, swap

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


public test() {

super("Checker and Swapper");

getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(15);
JButton check = new JButton("CHECK");
check.setActionCommand("check");



JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(15);
JButton swap = new JButton ("SWAP");
swap.setActionCommand("swap");


check.addActionListener(this);
swap.addActionListener(this);


getContentPane().add(textField1);
getContentPane().add(check);
getContentPane().add(textField2);
getContentPane().add(swap);


setSize(300, 170);
setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e)
{
    // i don't know what to put here
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
  new test();
}
}
```

So I'm trying to make a gui where if I click the button "check" it will check if the string on the two textfield is the same then a label would show up in the lower part is the same then if I click swap it will swap the two string.

I'm a beginner with gui. Can anyone help me?

Thanks (:

[This is what I already have expect for action for the button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goa7A.jpg)

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this?

Comment: @user3437460 yes, more explanations and examples from others would help me.

Comment: @NIece which part have you not understood?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code now it creates a popup using JOPtionPane if u need a label just use JLabel lblname = new JLabel() and add that to the frame and set the label text by calling lblname.setText("text");

```
public class test extends JFrame {

public test() {

this.setTitle("Checker and Swapper");
getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(15);
JButton check = new JButton("CHECK");
check.setActionCommand("check");

JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(15);
JButton swap = new JButton ("SWAP");
swap.setActionCommand("swap");

check.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      if(textField1.getText().equals(textField2.getText()))
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Both Texts are equal");
      }
    }
});

swap.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      String temporary = textField1.getText();
      textField1.setText(textField2.getText());
      textField2.setText(temporary);
    }
});


getContentPane().add(textField1);
getContentPane().add(check);
getContentPane().add(textField2);
getContentPane().add(swap);


setSize(300, 170);
setVisible(true);
}
```